# How to find big-0 of a nested loop

Tags: big-o

I assume "length" is my N. When I calculate my inner loop, second while loop, I get 3i+1. But when we calculate big-o, it should be N based. My professor gives 3i+1 = 3/2n^2-1/2n. But he didn't show me the procedure.

```
int dup_chk(int a[], int length) {
    int i = length;
    while (i > 0) {
         i--;
         int j = i - 1;
         while (j >= 0) {
             if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                 return 1;
             }
             j--;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Second while loop runs `J` times , with

```
if condition O(1) + j-- O(1)
```

Whereas `return` will run only once when `O(1)`

this is : `2J+1`